# How to make parse-server detect I'm using ESM now?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-server

I want to use ESM instead of CommonJS in my Node.js server is used to run ParseServer (version 6.4.0). I adapt my code. However, Parse-Server doesn't detect that I'm using ECM now and is throwing the following error:

```
require() of ES Module ../main.js from ../node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js not supported.
Instead change the require of main.js in ../node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

I found a solution by forcing the use of ESM via my npm start command : `npm_package_type=module node app.js`

But that's not a viable solution, as it should work from scratch.

To switch to ESM, I change theses line in my package.json :

```
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  },
```

I also use import/export in all my files. What should I also do to make parse-server aware I'm now in ECM?

Looking into parseServer code, it crashes here:

```
   if (process.env.npm_package_type === 'module' || ((_json = json) === null || _json === void 0 ? void 0 : _json.type) === 'module') {
            await import(path.resolve(process.cwd(), cloud));
          } else {
            require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), cloud));
          }
```

It crashes because it goes into the require part which is not allow for ESM instead of the import part. It only works when I change my `npm start` command and force it.

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting ? And are you running or windows or lunix based machine ?

Comment: @SuatKarabacak Here's the full error:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ../main.js from ../node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js not supported.
Instead change the require of main.js in ../node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at new ParseServer (../node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:158:9)
    at new _ParseServer (../node_modules/parse-server/lib/index.js:88:18)
    at file:///../app.js:45:16 {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
I'm on a linux based machine

Comment: did you try that? https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example/issues/432#issuecomment-1535963633

Comment: Even when I modify ParseServer code with the code of the link, I still have the same error. If I try to change main.js to main.cjs and use require, the error is move to the first file I require in the main.cjs

Comment: Finally, I might have a solution following what you send me. I'll tell you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a solution using this [link](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example/issues/432#issuecomment-1535963633) that @SuatKarabacak suggested.

To make it works, I have to create a async function in my `main.js` then export it as a default. It look like:

```
const cloud = async function() {
    await import("./file.js"); // it contains cloud functions
    /**
     * parse bindings
     * @type {ParseClass}
     */
    const ParseClass = (await import("./ParseClass.js"))["default"];

    Parse.Object.registerSubclass("ParseClass", ParseClass);
}

export default cloud;
```

Then in my `index.js`, I imported it:

```
import cloud from "./cloud/main.js";
```

and I use it directly in the config object of ParseServer

```
new ParseServer({
cloud,
...
});
```

I don't test if my classes have issues and I'll let you know if that's the case but my cloud functions work.